# Wordpress javascript file loaded using script-loader.php file is not updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hi i have created wordpress website using wordpress 4.7.5 on localhost xampp php 7.0 and i have not made any changes to wordpress installation like adding plugin or any other modfication. I wanted wordpress to execute extra code when i set featured image. For that 
i wish to modify media-editor.js file to add customization when user click on set featured image button in wordpress. But when i changed media-editor code and saved file the changed code is not updated in browser. I tried on both chrome and mozilla firefox browser. I cleared both browser cache and i also tried reload using CTRL +  R. The file is loaded using script-loader.php file. I even renamed js folder name still no change.
        I can't use solution of changing version name as php function in the file script-loader.php is adding this files to wordpress. The code to add file is as follows.

```
$scripts->add( 'media-views',  "/wp-includes/js/media-views$suffix.js",  array( 'utils', 'media-models', 'wp-plupload', 'jquery-ui-sortable', 'wp-mediaelement' ), false, 1 );
$scripts->add( 'media-editor', "/wp-includes/js/media-editor$suffix.js", array( 'shortcode', 'media-views' ), false, 1 );
```

when i view source code wordpress is creating min file which is as follows.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,heartbeat,autosave,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,sug&amp;load%5B%5D=gest,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,wp-a11y,jquery&amp;load%5B%5D=-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,tags-box,underscore,word-count,post,editor-expand,thickbox,shortcode,backbone,wp-util,wp-backbone,&amp;load%5B%5D=media-models,wp-plupload,mediaelement,wp-mediaelement,media-views,media-editor,media-audiovideo,mce-view,imgareaselect,image-edi&amp;load%5B%5D=t,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,editor,wplink,media-upload,wp-embed&amp;ver=4.7.5'></script>
```

What should i do to make sure that updated code is added to wordpress. Is wordpress have any inbuilt caching functionality which preventing from change in those files because i have already cleared browser chache and tried reloading page on both chrome and mozilla

Comment: I have already tried clearing cache and reload.

Comment: Are you literally editing core WP files?

Comment: Basically i need to call few api when user click on set featured image that is why i am modifying media-editor.js core wp files. I am not pro wordpress developer is there any other way to call api or execute extra code when user click on set featured image without modifying code wp file.

Comment: Firstly, you SHOULD NEVER EDIT any core file. This is bad bad and dangerous. There are many ways to override WP functions. Better you have a child theme. To answer your questions, you need to give more details of your code and its outcome. You need to mention what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: I wish to execute extra code when user click on set featured image.Like call few api i don't have url of these api as of right now. I wish to call these api when user click on set featured image.

Comment: I am afraid to say that you need to elaborate more on this. You need to define your "extra code". Anyway, click is a JS event. You better install a child theme, create a js file there and then enqueue the file. Then place all your click events in that file. Read more on this here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177157/i-want-to-enqueue-a-js-file-to-my-child-theme#comment258257_177160

Comment: Thanks for answer Ayanize. The website i am talking don't have child theme and as website is already in use i can't make many changes like adding child theme as it might break existing functionality.Is it possible to execute 2 scripts when user click set featured images and extra code is for calling external api like ajax code.